# Invalid Entitlement.plist for my iphone?

Tags: iphone

i m sending .ipa file and ad-hoc provisional profile to my friend for installing my application in his iphone through itunes of windowsXP
But it shows invalid entitlement.plist for his iphone.
please reply me as soon as possible,
And i also does not know about importance of entitlement.plist file.
Thanks in advance for sending me answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you build an ad-hoc, make sure that you have created an entitlements.plist file (this is just for ad-hoc) and that `get-task-allow` is `false` (i.e., not checked).

You also have to make sure that your entitlements.plist file is specified in your ad-hoc build configuration. It is under the *Code Signing* section an set in the *Code Signing Entitlements* row.

Comment: Jason Coco,
I have done this process but still facing the problem. where i m wrong?
Do u have any idea to how to create entitlement.plist(members of .plist file) file?

Comment: @Rajendra Bhole: You are sure that get-task-allow is set to false? Normally you create it by adding a new file to your project, and you chose Code Signing Entitlements. By default, the plist that is created has a single element, get-task-allow, but this is set to TRUE by default! So you must edit this file and set to FALSE.

Comment: Coco:Thanks, your given process was right, i also did that similar one but I got solution on my question when i trying to had R&D on Entitlements.
I forget added the appropriate version of provisioning profile into the binary of the project, thats way it given me the error like that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my ipa. When I was doing the "distribute for enterprise" I was leaving the signing option by default. If you just select in the drop down list "Don't Sign" it should work. At least, for me it fixed the problem.